# sqlalchemy group_by error

Tags: group-by, sqlalchemy

The following works

```
s = select([tsr.c.kod]).where(tsr.c.rr=='10').group_by(tsr.c.kod)
```

and this does not:

```
s = select([tsr.c.kod, tsr.c.rr, any fields]).where(tsr.c.rr=='10').group_by(tsr.c.kod)
```

Why?

thx.

Comment: Did you figured out how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the query isn't valid like that.

Every column needs to be in the `group_by` or needs an aggregate (i.e. `max()`, `min()`, whatever) according to the SQL standard. Most databases have always complied to this but there are a few exceptions.

MySQL has always been the odd one in this regard, within MySQL this behaviour depends on the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` setting: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

I would personally recommend setting the `sql_mode` setting to `ANSI`. That way you're largely compliant to the SQL standard which will help you in the future if you ever need to use (or migrate) to a standards compliant database such as PostgreSQL.

Comment: I was seeing this as a SQL Alchemy issue, but actually SQL Alchemy is just doing what it is told and relaying the group by to the SQL engine. The underlying issue was MySQL changed it's behaviour to require every column to be in the group by in the 5.7 series.

Comment: @Mark the SQL standard specifies that all columns in a `GROUP BY` query should be either specified in the `GROUP BY` clause or need to be an aggregate. Most databases have always enforced this, MySQL only enforces this when the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` setting is enabled: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is somehow valid in mysql, but invalid in standard sql, postgresql and common sense. When you group rows by 'kod', each row in a group has the same 'kod' value, but different values for 'rr' for example. With aggregate functions you can get some aspect of the values in this column for each group, for example

select kod, max(rr) from table group by kod

will give you list of 'kod's and the max of 'rr's in each group (by kod).

That being sad, in the select clause you can only put columns from the group by clause and/or aggregate functions from other columns. You can put whatever you like in where - this is used for filtering. You can also put additional 'having' clause after group that contains aggregate function expression that can also be used as post-group filtering.